# Jest manual mocks does not use mock file in CRA

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, create-react-app

I have a CRA app and am trying to the use the [manual mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) feature of Jest, but my manual mocks does not seem to be applied.

I use a base url of `src` (by setting it in `tsconfig.json`). Simplified, I have  and have a file structure of

```
src/
|- components/
|-- Foo/
|--- index.js
|--- Foo.jsx
|- App.js
|- App.test.js
```

where `App.js` uses `import Foo from "components/Foo"`. In `App.test.js` I want `Foo` to be mocked (it's computationally heavy and tested in unit tests). So in my test I added `jest.mock("components/Foo")` and in my desperation added several `__mocks__` folders like

```
__mocks__
|- components\
|-- Foo.jsx
src/
|- __mocks__/
|-- components/
|--- Foo.jsx
|- components/
|-- Foo/
|--- __mocks__
|---- Foo.js
|--- index.js
|--- Foo.jsx
|- App.js
|- App.test.js
```

where each manual mock contains

```
console.log("Mock imported");

export default function MyMock(){
  console.log("Mock used");
  return <p />;
}
```

However, when running the tests no there are no console printouts from the mock and although `Foo` is assigned an empty mock, it does not use the intended manual mock.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: can you share test file as well? also, just making sure, you are having relative path in ```jest.mock()```, right?  like ```import SoundPlayer from './sound-player'; jest.mock('./sound-player'); // SoundPlayer is now a mock constructor```

Comment: No, I use absolute paths, both inside `App.js` and `App.test.js`. Is that what might be causing the problems? Using relative paths is difficult as I am working on a very large application

Answer (score 1):

Creating mock is a 3 step process:

1. In `App.js` `import Foo from 'components/Foo'` imports `Foo/index.js`. Inside components create `__mocks__/Foo/index.js` and export mock component.
2. Create a setup file for jest in project root `jest.setup.js` and declare `jest.mock('src/components/Foo')`
3. In jest config, add option `setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js']`

Comment: I put the `__mocks__` folder directly inside the `Foo` folder with an `index.js` inside `__mocks__`, then it worked as intended.

Comment: Yes, the file path for mock file inside mocks directory should match exactly with parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your file structure is incorrect. The `__mocks__` directory should immediately under components

```
src/
|- components/
|-- Foo.js 
|-- __mocks__
|--- Foo.jsx
|- App.js
|- App.test.js
```

Now Foo.js on main module directory can be something like this

```
function Foo() {
    return (
     
       <h1> Foo</h1>
    );
  }

  export default Foo;
```

And __mocks/Foo.js can be

```
console.log("Mock imported");

function Foo() {
    return (
     
       <h1> Mock</h1>
    );
  }

  export default Foo;
```

App.test.js will contain jest.mock call

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';


jest.mock("./components/Foo");

test('renders learn react link', () => {

 
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/Mock/i); // Check that MOCK component is called
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

**See the git repository for working sample
https://github.com/meera/jest_mock**

Comment: Thanks for the repo. However, how should it be treated if `Foo` is a folder containing an `index.js`  and a `Foo.jsx` file? `index.js` contains `export {default} from "./Foo";`

Comment: I realized that `__mocks__` should be inside the `Foo` folder and contain an `index.js` file. Then it works as intended

Comment: @JohanBook you're saying there needs to be a  `src/components/Foo/__mocks__/index.js` file?

Comment: I updated the repository - It should work even if Foo is a folder containing an index.js and Foo.jsx file.